# PHPUnit test passes when it should fail

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am writing a PHPUnit test suite and have run into a bit of a problem.

Here is the test:

```
public function testSomething(){
  $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('\core\classes\ImportedFile');

  $stub->expects($this->exactly(4))
       ->method('thismethoddoesntexist');

  $this->markTestIncomplete('not finished implementing');
}
```

For some reason this test is not failing. It should because the method does not exist and is therefore not called even once, let alone 4 times. It doesn't matter what I put in there, even if I put in a method name that does exist and say that I'm expecting it to run 100,000 times it still passes when this is obviously wrong.

I find this very strange since I have similar checks in previous tests which work properly.

Has anyone else experienced problems like this?

Comment: I don't see that you're actually calling any methods or assert anything... you're setting up expectations, but your test doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, the test is only partway through being written - I will obviously add some method calls etc. to this. I still think it should be a test failure though, since I'm expecting a method to be called and it isn't.

Comment: `markTestIncomplete` is designed to prevent your test from failing.  It isn't passing but your test suite will say that all the tests passed. http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.incomplete-tests.examples.SampleTest.php

Comment: @Schleis I think there is some inconsistency though - if I create a test that consists only of `$this->assertTrue(false)` and then a call to `markTestIncomplete`, PHPUnit rightly fails the test. So why doesn't it do that in my example above?

Comment: Because the failed assertion is marked by an exception that prevents the call to `markTestIncomplete` from ever being called.  In your case, the checks for mocks happen after the test has been completed.  So `markTestIncomplete` is called and the test is marked as Incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem. It seems to be caused by the call to `$this->markTestIncomplete()`. For some reason having this in the test causes it not to fail, at least in this case, even when it should.

Removing the call to `markTestIncomplete` makes it behave normally and fail when it should. I tend to leave the `markTestIncomplete` method in a test until it is 100% complete, and assume that if I run the test, even in its incomplete state, it should fail if an expectation is not met. Is this not a fair assumption to make? Is this a bug in PHPUnit?

Comment: I use [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) for my testing, so my experience is a little different, but Mockery requires a call to `Mockery::close()` after the test is run to properly resolve method call expectations. Perhaps something similar is required?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I'm not aware of anything like that in PHPUnit. I'll do a bit of googling.

Answer (score 2):

markTestIncomplete throw special exception, witch end the test. Checks for 'expects' in mocks are skipped.

```
public static function markTestIncomplete($message = '')
    {
        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_IncompleteTestError($message);
    }
```